# unset $_SESSION not working

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Hi i made a code that connects with facebook and register the user, then it makes the user login , everything works very nice.. When they login i set

```
$_SESSION['id']
```

My guess was, if this was unset the user will be logout from my site, and it wont be "autoreconnected"..

Because previously it was like a loop, everytime i logout, it login again using the facebook connect even if the user havent clic again "login with facebook"...

EDIT: I change a condition and know is not "looping" i CAN logout of the site..

But the Session , is not unset!, why, just the cookies are set to '' but ,=( session is not unset

Here is my code

the head

```
<?php
//
// uses the PHP SDK. Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
include("facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php");

//
// from the facebook app page
define('YOUR_APP_ID', '');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '');

//
// new facebook object to interact with facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
 'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));
//
// if user is logged in on facebook and already gave permissions
// to your app, get his data:
$userId = $facebook->getUser();

?>
```

The body

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['id'];

if ($userId) {
 //
 // already logged? show some data
 $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);





 if (isset($userInfo['email']) || isset($_SESSION['id']))

{ include "facebookregister.php"; } else { echo "no hay permisos de facebook"; }

} else {
 //
 // use javaascript api to open dialogue and perform
 // the facebook connect process by inserting the fb:login-button
 ?>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:login-button scope='email,user_birthday'></fb:login-button>
 <?php
}
?>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>,
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });


FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok
 window.location.reload();
 });
 };

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

facebookregister.php

```
<?PHP 
echo "<p>YOU ARE: <strong>". $userInfo['name'] ."</strong><br/>";
echo "Your birth date is: ".$userInfo['birthday']."</p>";
echo "Your mail is: ".$userInfo['email']."</p>";

echo "Your mail is: ".$userInfo['username']."</p>";



//$name = $userInfo['name'];
$first_name = $userInfo['first_name'];
$last_name = $userInfo['last_name'];
$birthday = $userInfo['birthday'];
$username_fb = $userInfo['username'];
$email = $userInfo['email'];
$gender = $userInfo['gender'];
$status = 1;

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}


    $db= DAL::get_instance();           



    //select all rows from our users table where the emails match
                                    $count=$db->read_single_column("select count(id) from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where email=? and status=1", array($email));
 echo "Aqui".$count;
                                    //if the number of matchs is 1
                                    if($count == 1){
                                        //the email address supplied is taken so just login user 


                                    $res=$db->execute_query("select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where email=?",array($email));
                    $v=$res->fetch_assoc();
                    $username=$v['username'];
                    $password=$v['password'];



            $this->set_variable('username',$username);
                    $this->set_variable('password',$password);


                    $query="select id from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where username=? and password=?";
                    $res=$db->execute_query($query,array($username,$password));

                    $value2=$res->fetch_assoc();
                    $id=$value2['id'];
                    $orig_password=$db->read_single_column("select password from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where username=? and status=1", array($username));




                    if($password == $orig_password)
                    {
                        $t=time();
                        $sql="update ".TABLE_PREFIX."users set last_login_time=? where id=?";
                        $res=$db->execute_query($sql,array($t,$id));




                        $srv_nms=BASE;
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


                        $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

                        $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


                        $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);


                        setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,$id,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
                        setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,$username,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
                        setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,$orig_password,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;          

        if(LoginHelper::validate_user_login()==0)
        {
            header("Location:index.php");
            exit;
        }


        }


                                    }else{

    //finally, otherwise register there account

                                        //time of register (unix)
                                        $registerTime = date('U');

                                        //make a code for our activation key
                                        $code = md5($username).$registerTime;

                                            $password = $randomString;

                                        $password  = md5($password);

                                        //insert the row into the database
                                         $res=$db->execute_query("INSERT INTO ".TABLE_PREFIX."users (`username`, `password`, `email`, `reg_time`, `status`, `fname`, `lname`) VALUES('".$username_fb."','".$password."','".$email."','".$registerTime."','".$status."','".$first_name."' ,'".$last_name."'  )");

                                        $row=$db->execute_query("SELECT username, password FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE email=".$email."");
                $row_data=$row->fetch_assoc();

                $username=$row_data['username'];
                $password=$row_data['password'];


            $this->set_variable('username',$username);
                    $this->set_variable('password',$password);


                    $query="select id from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where username=? and password=?";
                    $res=$db->execute_query($query,array($username,$password));

                    $value2=$res->fetch_assoc();
                    $id=$value2['id'];
                    $orig_password=$db->read_single_column("select password from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users where username=? and status=1", array($username));


                    if(md5($password)== $orig_password)
                    {
                        $t=time();
                        $sql="update ".TABLE_PREFIX."users set last_login_time=? where id=?";
                        $res=$db->execute_query($sql,array($t,$id));




                        $srv_nms=BASE;
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


                        $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

                        $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
                        $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


                        $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);


                        setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,$id,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
                        setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,$username,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
                        setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,$orig_password,0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);

                        $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;              



            //header("Location:".$this->make_url('user/home'));
            //exit;

                }                       


                                        //send the email with an email containing the activation link to the supplied email address
                                        mail($email, $username.' registration confirmation', "Thank you for registering to us ".$username.",\n\nHere is your activation link. If the link doesn't work copy and paste it into your browser address bar.\n\nhttp://www.yourwebsitehere.co.uk/activate.php?code=".$code, 'From: noreply@youwebsitehere.co.uk');

                                        //display the success message
                                        echo "<center>You have successfully registered, please visit you inbox to activate your account!</center>";


            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
                                    }







        ?>
```

THE MOST IMPORTANT. LOGOUT ACTION

```
function logout_action()
    {
        $srv_nms=BASE;
        $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


        $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

        $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
        $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


        $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);


        setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
        setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);

        unset($_SESSION['user']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_540341239342331_code']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_540341239342331_access_token']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_540341239342331_user_id']);


        header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l"));
        die;
    }
```

Session unset & destroy, tested but not working.. why??
Code

```
function logout_action()

{
    $srv_nms=BASE;
    $srv_nms=str_replace("http://","",$srv_nms);
    $srv_nms=str_replace("https://","",$srv_nms);
    $srv_nms=str_replace("www.","",$srv_nms);


    $srv_pats=$srv_nms;

    $srv_nms_arr=explode("/",$srv_nms);
    $srv_nms=$srv_nms_arr[0];


    $srv_pats=str_replace($srv_nms."/","",$srv_pats);


    setcookie(COOKIE_LOGINID,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
    setcookie(COOKIE_USERNAME,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);
    setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);

    session_unset();


    header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l"));
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not recommended to unset session variables this way. Use `session_unset()`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Over that, you don't want that the session still exists on the users computer, for this use `session_destroy()`.

> `session_unset()` just clears out the session for usage.

Comment: Ok so i replace all that unset session code with "session_unset()" no more values given

Comment: thanks very much for your answer and comments.. but im doing something wrong, because also session_destroy() can´t logout a user from the site

Comment: Are you sure you're script isn't recreating those sessions when you reload the page for testing purposes? You can check the list of cookies registered by your site inside your browser, that might help troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: After `session_destroy()` the session is really "destroyed", so it seems like you are recreating the session somewhere again. Maybe on the action that is called after redirecting with header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l"));?

Comment: yes i know, thats why i add this "if (isset($userInfo['email']) || isset($_SESSION['id']))

{ include "facebookregister.php"; } " but its not working.. THATS MY QUESTION..

Comment: the values of Session are created in facebookregister.php

Comment: The same as user id.. because when the suceffully login i set userid as Session ID...But it must be null or not set, if i use Session _unset so , where and why is set again.. if there is a condition saying, if session[id] is not set, dont do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your logout script add these lines after `setcookie(COOKIE_PASSWORD,"",0,"/".$srv_pats,$srv_nms);`

```
include("facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php");

//
// from the facebook app page
define('YOUR_APP_ID', '_');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '_');

//
// new facebook object to interact with facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
 'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));
$logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array("next"=>'your url after user logs out'));
$facebook->destroySession();
//destroy your sessions created by your site also using session_destroy();

/* don't forget to remove header("Location: ".$this->make_url("user/login/l")); */
header("Location:$logout");
```

Comment: But this wont logout the user from facebook?? i just want to log the user out of my site, not from facebook... im gonna test it anyway, thanks, :D maybe this is what i need!! :D

Comment: I tested but it takes me to the Facebook page, and if i clic back, to my page, its logged out! but it auto login the user jaja, so it wont fit my needs :(

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the url provided in `$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array("next"=>'your url after user logs out'));`. What url did you provide?

Comment: Ok. This is a well known problem which may be caused due to many factors. Lets narrow it down. Open a new private mode in your browser. Don't login to your facebook account. Login to your site using facebook login provided in your site. Once logged in then try to log out.

Comment: Good! Now back to your old browser, log out from facebook account in facebook.com and  go to your site and manually clear all the cookies of your site. Then try logging in and it should work fine.

Comment: Well now im logged out of the site =) but, the session is not unset.. still print the user id =(...

Comment: the problem is caused because of the existence of PHPSESSIONID cookie in your site. Close the existing browser and open it again and then try login and logout.

User id will still be displayed in your site even when you have logged out from facebook.com