# unset of the error message not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

Unset of the session for the error message is not working. When I click on `Login` button with empty fields, however, the session works but if I refresh/ reload the page then error message `Undefined index: message in...` appears in this line `unset($_SESSION['message']);`

I looked into these questions:
[Login error message in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717032/login-error-message-in-php)
[display error message on same page for login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129273/display-error-message-on-same-page-for-login)
[unset $_SESSION not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762179/unset-session-not-working)
[Session unset function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762179/unset-session-not-working)

& I added the solutions mentioned in those questions but I ended up with error.
What's wrong with the code?

**home.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connect.php';  //successful connection to db
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function login(file, div){
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhttp.open('GET',file,true); 
        xhttp.send();       
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
        <form action="loginform.php" method="GET">
            Username:<input type="text" name="uname"></br>          
            Password:<input type="password" name="pass"></br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="login('loginform.php','errormsg');"><br>

            <div id="errormsg">
                <?php
                    if($_SESSION['message']){
                        echo $_SESSION['message']; 
                        unset($_SESSION['message']);//works for blank or wrong inputs but if page is refreshed error: 'Undefined index: message in...' appears in this line.
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**loginform.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['uname']) && isset($_GET['pass'])){
    $uname = $_GET['uname'];
    $pass = $_GET['pass'];

    if(!empty($uname) && !empty($pass)){ 
        $query = "SELECT `Username` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `Username`='$uname' AND `Password`='$pass'";
        $query_run=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

        if($num_row == 1){
            header('Location:welcome.php');
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Wrong Username or Password missing.';
            header('Location:home.php');
        }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Enter values';
            header('Location:home.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your php code at **home.php** like this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message'] != ''){
            echo $_SESSION['message']; 
            unset($_SESSION['message']);//works for blank or wrong inputs but if page is refreshed error: 'Undefined index: message in...' appears in this line.
        }
?>
```

Because you need to check by `isset()` that your session variable `message` is set or not,

Also for more info about isset(), check it out http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2):

The line that is giving the error is two lines above that.

You should use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
```

instead of:

```
if($_SESSION['message'])
```

This will check if the index exists rather than if the value is not 0.

Comment: what a silly mistake that I made...Thank you for your effort! Now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code in home.php

```
<div id="errormsg">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['message']) && !empty($_SESSION['message'])){
            echo $_SESSION['message']; 
            unset($_SESSION['message']);//works for blank or wrong inputs but if page is refreshed error: 'Undefined index: message in...' appears in this line.
        }
        ?>
        </div>
```

Hope this code will help you